# indexed-db websql ydn-db storing uploaded data

Tags: javascript, file-upload, indexeddb, web-sql, ydn-db

I am trying to save the uploaded data eg. img,txt,xls into the indexeddb or websql using ydn-db

But I am getting this error in chrome
U**ncaught DataCloneError: An object could not be cloned. while trying to insert a blob object**.

Can I have a simple example on how I can insert blobs in indexed-db?

Also a few Question :

1.I have arraybuffer of the file uploaded but I am able insert it in idnexeddb and retrive it by keeping the field type = TEXT in ydn .But it doesnt work in safari... it returns me a object with no data .

2.What is the maximum size limit of string and other types which we can insert in a field in indexed-db and websql with ydn?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is yet to support cloning Blob.

1. I don't think WebSQL support ArrayBuffer.
2. No limit, but if you are asking this question, it is leading to wrong direction. Din't index it at all.

You can get best compatibility by storing your raw data without structure.

Comment: What do you mean by my raw data structure? Can you specify exactly which thing shall I insert in ydn which will be supported cross browser.For this file upload script.